# QuickSort Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, quicksort

My generic QuickSort algorithm has two problems that I can't determine the cause of.

1. The list is sometimes not correctly sorted
2. When dealing with lists larger than 20,000 items, I often get stack overflows if the values repeat a lot (which I presume isn't supposed to be a real issue)

The list not being sorted correctly is a fairly rare occurrence, so the list has to be reasonably large.
The paste below shows the first 13 elements of a 172-element list of installed software with the first column showing the output after the first sort, and second column for a second sort.

```
Adobe AIR                         7-Zip 4.65 (x64 edition)
7-Zip 4.65 (x64 edition)          Adobe AIR
Adobe Community Help              Adobe Community Help
Adobe Encore CS4 Codecs           Adobe Encore CS4 Codecs
Adobe Media Encoder CS4 Exporter  Adobe Media Encoder CS4 Exporter
Adobe Media Encoder CS4 Importer  Adobe Media Encoder CS4 Importer
Adobe Media Player                Adobe Media Player
Adobe Reader X (10.1.0)           Adobe Reader X (10.1.0)
Adobe Setup                       Adobe Setup
Adobe Setup                       Adobe Setup
Apple Application Support         Adobe Setup
Adobe Setup                       Apple Application Support
Apple Mobile Device Support       Apple Mobile Device Support
...                               ...
```

As you can see, the first time it was sorted, there is some incorrect behaviour, which is fixed by doing another sort.

The second problem with stack overflows happens if I sort my big-ol' Windows Event Log list. It seems to be happy if I sort 52,000 dates spanning 4 weeks; but if I sort 52,000 ID numbers which have many repeats, my stack size becomes 998 items long before it crashes the system. It also happens if I sort a 30,000 long list by a column which is mostly 'gupdate'.

Now, as far as I can see, the stack count should be log2(n) because the amount added to the stack is equal to the amount of cutting-in-half that is done.

I made my pivot random to aid this effect, but it didn't make a lot of difference.

Log2(60000) = 16. That's not enough for a stack overflow!

This is the code in concern:

```
private static void QuickSortFunction<T>(T[] array, int start, int end, Comparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (end - start >= 1)
    {
        int leftPtr, rightPtr, pivot;
        Random random = new Random();
        pivot = random.Next(start, end);
        Swap(array, pivot, start);
        pivot = start;

        leftPtr = start + 1;
        rightPtr = end;

        while (leftPtr < rightPtr)
        {
            while ((comparer.Compare(array[leftPtr], array[pivot])) <= 0 && (leftPtr < rightPtr))
            {
                leftPtr++;
            }

            while ((comparer.Compare(array[rightPtr], array[pivot])) >= 0 && (leftPtr <= rightPtr))
            {
                rightPtr--;
            }

            if (leftPtr < rightPtr)
            {
                Swap(array, leftPtr, rightPtr);
            }
        }
        Swap(array, pivot, rightPtr);
        pivot = rightPtr;

        QuickSortFunction(array, start, pivot - 1, comparer);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end, comparer);
    }
}

private static void Swap<T>(T[] array, int pointer1, int pointer2)
{
    T temp = array[pointer1];
    array[pointer1] = array[pointer2];
    array[pointer2] = temp;
}
```

For anyone interested, this is the fix for the out-of-order glitch. Basically, it was failing to recognise a 2-element array when it was out of order. Such as {E, B}, which it would not change because it wouldn't look at its own pivot.

```
    if (end - start >= 1)
    {
        int leftPtr, rightPtr, pivot;
        Random random = new Random();
        pivot = random.Next(start, end);
        Swap(array, pivot, start);
        pivot = start;

        leftPtr = start;
        rightPtr = end;

        while (leftPtr < rightPtr)
        {
            while ((comparer.Compare(array[leftPtr], array[pivot])) < 0 && (leftPtr < rightPtr))
            {
                leftPtr++;
            }

            while ((comparer.Compare(array[rightPtr], array[pivot])) >= 0 && (leftPtr < rightPtr))
            {
                rightPtr--;
            }

            if (leftPtr < rightPtr)
            {
                Swap(array, leftPtr, rightPtr);
            }
        }
        Swap(array, pivot, rightPtr);
        pivot = rightPtr;

        QuickSortFunction(array, start, pivot - 1, comparer);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end, comparer);
    }
```

Will update once I write a solution for the stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah... Don't do that recursively. Try a `for` loop instead.

Comment: P.s, is there a neat way to count my stack for the 52,000 date sort in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Mark - the for loop would exchange the stack overflow (infinite recursion) with an infifinite loop.  If you meant that the logic is easier so it's less likely to make a mistake that causes infinite loop, you should support that somehow

Comment: A bit besides the point: Don't create a `Random` instance in a loop (or recursion). Use a static field of the class and initialise it only once.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to write your own quicksort instead of using the built-in quicksort algorithm in Array.sort?

Comment: Also, just a quick thing I noticed, I think this algorithm will fail to sort a list of length 2. If start is 0 and end is 1, it doesn't even look at the elements, right? (1 - 0 is not greater than 1.)

Comment: @BlueMonkMN One reason is that this way, I can sort anything (including a List View using a custom IComparer), and it also gets me more marks in my coursework if I have hand-written an algorithm like this.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN True true, adjusted the code to suit 2 elements.
Although I could make it skip if there are 3 elements, but I'd have to prove that a 3-element list is already sorted which I did once but forgot.

Comment: @Attila if there is a second issue, then yes: that needs fixing too - but this really shouldn't be recursive.

Comment: @MarcGravell Aren't all versions of the Quicksort algortihm recursive? And they shouldn't use definite loops anywhere because the order of the elements will always be uncertain.

Comment: @CJxD there's two versions of recursive - *logically* recursive, vs *operationally* recursive. In many cases, something that is *logically* recursive may be cleverly implemented without *actual* recursion, to avoid stack explosion. Tail-call is also sometimes an option, depending of the language and runtime.

Comment: @CJxD There are 17 overloads of Array.sort alone, many of which accept custom compare objects and comparison functions. One of the overloads accepts the same parameters (including templates) yours does: T[] array, int index, int length, IComparer<T> comparer. It's a static function so it operates exactly like yours. (Except, presumably, it works. :) )

Answer (score 1):

> Now, as far as I can see, the stack count should be log2(n) because the amount added to the stack is equal to the amount of cutting-in-half that is done.

That's only true if you split the input into halves of similar<sup>1</sup> size. If, for example, you're sorting a list where all the items are equal, you get a very uneven split where you have no elements on one side and everything except the pivot on the other. In that case, you get *O(n)* stack size since each level only reduces the input size by 1.

One way of avoiding this is to use a three-way partitioning instead which places all the elements equal to the pivot in the middle.

<sub><sup>1</sup>If the split is always better than some constant ratio, you're fine.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.
I am however limited to how much of the algorithm I can change. Three-way partitioning I'm guessing would probably differ from my original algorithm too much which would be difficult to explain later in the project. (This is coursework for the record).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the out-of-order issue first.  the big loop goes until `leftPtr >= rightPtr`.  Since your second loop tests for `leftPtr <= rightPtr`, it is possible that at the end `leftPtr > rightPtr`, in which case you are swapping (after the big loop) the pivot and an element that has been deemed "OK" (`rightPtr` points to something that has been passed by `leftPtr`)

Not sure about the stack overflow issue, but Hammar's suggestion seems reasonable especially that you said the problem occurs on large lists of many equal elements

Comment: I see what you're saying, but making adjustments to the logic will either make it worse or make an infinite loop.

Comment: The right adjustments took me 5 hours of procrastination. Updated the question to show the changes =]

Answer (score 0):

Watch the infinite loop you have created... the function must terminate for its intrinsic value to be actualized in use.